# ORA-01843: not a valid month when executing insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the query which is inserting a date with the format `year month day`, but I keep getting a same error saying `ORA-01843: not a valid month`. Looking the oracle docs it appears I am correct which is confusing. Hoping to get an extra set of eyes.

```
  to_timestamp('2018-07-02 08:03:24.466381 AM', 'RR-MON-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

and

```
to_timestamp('2115-07-21 00:00:00.0 AM', 'RR-MON-DD HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MON` is the format mask for the **name** of the month. As you are supplying the number, you need `MM`

```
to_timestamp('2018-07-02 08:03:24.466381 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mi.ssxff am')
```

And as you are supplying a four-digit year `yyyy` is probably a better choice than `rr`